# where did this maven archetypes list come from?

Tags: java, maven, build

Jetbrains IDEA when the moudle is created.

where did this maven archetypes list come from?

how do i update this list myself?except for manual increases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ is using an IntelliJ Maven plugin. The list is from Maven Central, and it is automatically downloaded by that plugin. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206173089-Maven-archetype-repository .

An equivalent command in terminal is `mvn archetype:generate`. A file is generated at `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`. You should be able to compare what's on screen to verify it is a matching list.

To force download, you can delete that file, and in the terminal run the earlier Maven command. If you want extra catalogs, the [request is open at IntelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206173089-Maven-archetype-repository). The [IntelliJ Maven Archetype Catalogs Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965-maven-archetype-catalogs) can also be used right now to download different catalogs.

Comment: Private repository, how does the company synchronize?

Comment: You must be running pass-through via Nexus or Artifactory or something? I believe those servers have facilities to scrub files at various intervals. Next request they should be reloaded in my experience.